# XML HTTP Request - Handle Loss of Connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Can someone expalain why this doesn't work right when the connection is good? If I lose connection it works perfect, however, if I still have connection is still shows the if and else responses.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("inventory-info-details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   $('.loader').toggleClass('load-complete');
   $('.checkmark').toggleClass('checkmarkShow');
   $("#tableDiv").load("inventoryList_printOut.php");
  }
  else
  {
  $("#loadError").css( "display", "block" );
  $("#inventory-info-details").css( "display", "none" );
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `XMLHttpRequest`, the `.onreadystatechange` is an event handler that gets called each time the `readyState` got changed. There are five of them ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)):

1. UNSENT (value 0)
2. OPENED (value 1)
3. HEADERS_RECEIVED (value 2)
4. LOADING (value 3)
5. DONE(value 4)

When using `new XMLHttpRequest()`, the `readyState` is 0. During the process (eg when using `.open(...)`, `.send(...)`) the `readyState` value changes. For each change, the function assigned to the `.onreadystatechange` is being executed.

During the process, it evaluates the following condition.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

Since the readyState did not reach the `DONE` status (value 4) yet, the above condition is false. Therefore, the `else` block is being executed. If you want to prevent that (with other words, only do the action when the request has been finished), please use this approach:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
    // handle on success
  }
  else {
    // handle error situation
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked, but how come it worked when the internet connection is good? When the internet connection is good, wouldn't it pass by the if condition, also?